# Configure Notepad++ for localhost browsing (NppFTP)

Tags: ftp, xampp, localhost, notepad++

I can't seem to get the `NppFTP` plugin to connect to my localhost (via XAMPP) for local development using **Notepad++**.

According to the `http://localhost/xampp/` docs, the default username and password are 'newuser' and 'wampp' accordingly.

I'm using these settings:

- host: 127.0.0.1
- port: 21
- username: newuser
- password: wampp
- initial remote directory: `C:/xampp/htdocs/myrootdirectory`

The console just says 'Quit' right after I try and connect.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? And if it's because localhost is not a remote directory, how do I configure Notepad++ to browse my local files without relying on Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't make sense to Filezilla into your localhost, you should just use the Notepad Plugin, Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on windows, make sure you're running your xampp control (xampp ui ) as admin. Then, you have yo check SVC checkbox before filezilla then click start. A pop-up will prompt and click Yes to install it as a service.

after that, click admin then click Yes. set you password then you're good to go.

In you're notepadd++, the settings are the same with the one you posted above.

Hope that helps.

Raul